# How can I get all of the columns that are displayed by default for a list?

Tags: list

I had assumed I could use `myList.DefaultView.ViewFields` but this does not seem to include the Title (which is part of my default columns list).  It does include, linkTitle, but this is a different value than what I want.

Is there something different that I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 available columns for the title: Title, LinkTitle, and LinkTitleNoMenu. If you click on the default view - in List Settings for your list, you will see that the column named Title (linked to item with edit menu) is checked, but the column named Title is not checked.

If you actually want the Title column with no link, you can change which columns are included in your view.

If you do not want to modify your view, but you want the Title column, you will need to get that from your list and not from the view.

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason when I try this with the built in Task list, it displays `1_.000`, `2_.000` for the `Title` column.  I found three different flavors of the `Title` column available but they all display the same thing.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't know why 1_.000, 2_.000 is showing up in the Title column. I've seen values like this in what look like files, but are actually a type of pointer to the correct version. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion.url.aspx)